# Case - why am i getting illegal lambda expression

Tags: haskell

```
 data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat 
 data NatSig val = NatSig {zero_ :: val, succ :: val -> val}

foldNat :: NatSig val -> Nat -> val

foldNat alg = \case Zero -> zero_ alg 
                    Succ n -> succ alg $ foldNat alg sn
```

Hello this is a code from my University but if i want to run it i get an error

```
Illegal lambda-case (use -XLambdaCase)
```

some
one know why?

Answer (score 9):

The syntax `\case` isn't in the Haskell Report, so it isn't allowed in standard Haskell. To use it, you have to enable the `LambdaCase` extension. There are several different ways you can do so, including:

1. Put `-XLambdaCase` on the command line
2. Put `{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}` at the top of the file
3. Run `:set -XLambdaCase` at the GHCi prompt